# A javascript error occured in the main process

Tags: javascript, error-handling, uncaught-exception

error: A javaScript error occured in the main process

uncaught Exception:
Error:EPERM:operation not permitted, open 'C:\ITAMEEssential\hideapp.ps1'

I keep receiving this error. How do I get around this?

If someone has already figured out the answers to these problems, please share or comment.
I'm not seeing a remedy for this, and there are no YouTube videos available either. If anyone knows how to fix this error, could you please share your thoughts and solutions?

[Click here to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9041I.png)

Comment: Please look at you question - it is missing even the error, let alone showing  us the code that is giving the error. Please edit to include these details.

Comment: Screenshots of your error will not make the cut. Post it as actual text.